# How to add images icon in the title bar of JFrame?

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe

I need to add image in `JFrame` title bar, can anybody tell me the way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`Window#setImageIcons(List<Image>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImages%28java.util.List%29) which allows you to supply a series of different sized, which allows the underlying platform to choose a icon that is best suited to the platform and look and feel...

```
List<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>(4);
images.add(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/icons/icon16x16.png"));
images.add(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/icons/icon24x24.png"));
images.add(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/icons/icon32x32.png"));
images.add(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/icons/icon48x48.png"));

frame.setImageIcons(images);
```

Comment: Multiple icons, +1.  E.G. as seen in [File Bro](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui).

Comment: You will get at least one error because `ImageIO.read` throws and `IOException` which I haven't wrapped in a try catch.  Other then that, what's the error

Answer (score 2):

use `frame.setIconImage(Image image)`
see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html for details.
Use `BufferedImage` to represent your image.