# Why my Icon is not changed in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Here is my Code in java that i have written. A screen shot of my Laptop is attached which is showing output in which java icon is still there on (left corner).

```
import javax.swing.*;![enter image description here][1]
import java.awt.*;

public class Frame
{
    public static void createWindow()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Warning");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel textLabel = new JLabel ("Congratulation!! Installation Complete.",      SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(420,140));
        frame.getContentPane().add(textLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("D:\\Icons\\icon.ico");
        frame.setIconImage(img.getImage());


        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        createWindow();
    }
```

}

Comment: Consult this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614772/how-to-change-jframe-icon

Comment: See this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817565/how-to-add-images-icon-in-the-title-bar-of-jframe

Comment: Try using a .png or .gif image file instead of an .ico file.

Comment: Thanks Buddy it is supporting jpg n png :)

Answer (score 1):

`..Icons\\icon.ico`

Does the JVM in question even *support* `.ico` files?  It is recommended to stick to PNG, GIF and JPEG.   Here is the list<sup>1</sup> of supported file types using Java 1.8 on a Windows 7 machine.

```
Reader  jpg
Reader  bmp
Reader  gif
Reader  png
Reader  jpeg
Reader  wbmp
Writer  jpg
Writer  bmp
Writer  gif
Writer  png
Writer  wbmp
Writer  jpeg
```

No `.ico` listed..

1. Information obtained from the `MediaTypes` code seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7616206/418556).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following if the link don't work fine to you. It's working for me:

use **setIconImage(...).**

```
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;
//upto here just importing. Don't worry, let the eclipse or your editor do that for you
class FrameIcons {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url16 = new URL("image.png");//Making two objects of URL class
        URL url32 = new URL("images.png");//second object of URL

        final List<Image> icons = new ArrayList<Image>();//this is just an arraylist of `icon. For now on if you don't know about list, think it as array where you can put element using .add() method`
        icons.add(ImageIO.read(url16));//adding to list
        icons.add(ImageIO.read(url32));//adding to list

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {//this is just for running a `runnable`
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Frame Icons");//setting JFrame
                f.setIconImages(icons);//setting icon images
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//you must know `everything from here`
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.setSize(200,100);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Buddy M new user. cant use this type of code its difficult for me. :(

Comment: It's not quite hard. I am gonna explain it for you. See the updates to the answer and let me know if you can pick me.

Comment: all is good but can't u edit my code just the getimage() line? actually m coding on text pad

Comment: if you are beginner to java, i wouldn't recommend you using a simple text editor. Try using Eclipse or other IDE. It will help you move faster

Comment: And let me know if it's working to you and ask what you don't know

Comment: @Nabin Never advice new users to use IDE. First It is always better to get your hands dirty with notepad or some text editor

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne Huh?? Beginners will spend time in just understanding the functions and classes. IDE will help them catch easily

Comment: @Nabin yeah IDE is easy. but then you understand nothing